# Error while trying to call a cloud function using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-auth-library

```
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library')
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    async function func1() {
      const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
      const requestOptions = {
        url: targetAudience,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: data
      }
      console.log("calling target audience")
      const res = await client.request(requestOptions);
      return res
    }


    console.log("calling func1")
    func1()
      .then(function (response) {
        return resolve({res: 'done'})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return resolve({res: 'fail' })
      })
```

I am trying to call an internal CF which is the target audience in this case.

I am getting the below error:
`Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 404`

"calling func1" is getting printed but "calling target audience" is not getting printed. Looks like it is failing before coming to this line:

`const res = await client.request(requestOptions);`

I am not sure why it is failing at this. I have checked the permissions given to the gcp service account and I dont see anything amiss. These are the permissions I have given:

```
Cloud Functions Admin
Service Account OpenID Connect Identity Token Creator
Service Account Token Creator
Storage Admin
```

Could anyone help me out here?

If I could identity the cause I might be able to proceed with finding a solution but I am not understanding why this error is coming. Target audience is correct and have observed that even if we give some string I saw that it would reach line:

`const res = await client.request(requestOptions);`

Currently even that is not happening. Is there some permission that I am missing or where am I going wrong?

Comment: Investigate why your URL is not found. That is not related to Identity Tokens. The error is `Request failed with status code 404`. 404 means `Not Found`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am confused because of this very reason. I have checked the url which is the target audience and it is running properly.

Comment: The `url` is incorrect. From your workstation run this command `curl -v REPLACE_ME_WITH_targetAudience`. Post the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if "targetAudience" exist. Also Double-check that the targetAudience is in the correct URL format for the Cloud Function. It should be in the format: https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME.

Comment: If I call the target audience separately it is working. I checked that.